# Raileasy split ticketing purchased

Tags: uk, trains, tickets

have bought but they have not reserved any seats as requested saying it is not possible.Will be travelling in 10 weeks time. Can I take tickets to the station of departure and ask for reserved seats in the meantime?

Comment: I travel on trains every day (West Coast Virgin Trains and London Northwestern) and normally there's always at least one seat that will be free.  Even if the train is packed there's always one seat somewhere. However, if you are travelling with a lot of luggage then you can probably ignore my comment as indeed a reservation makes life easier (though to an extent - if the train is packed there might not be space for luggage next to your reserved seat and you might have to shoo away the person who is sitting in the seat that is reserved for you).

Comment: If you tell us which train operator this is for we should be able to tell you if seat reservations would normally be possible.

Comment: nottingham via peterborough to norwich on east midland rail

Answer (score 2):

Yes, although you'll need to collect the tickets first and take them to the ticket office. It doesn't need to be the station of departure, any ticket office will be able to do so.

Although consider that whatever problem lead RailEasy to be unable to reserve may also effect the ticket office. Remember not all trains are capable of being reserved.

Source: Done so many time repeatedly, it's also mentioned on this national rail page: https://www.nationalrail.co.uk/times_fares/ticket_types/46581.aspx

Comment: Agree with some trains it might not be possible to reserve a seat.